# Estoy descargando un PDF desde C# pero quisiera que se me descargara en la carpeta descargas y no en la ruta del proyecto

Tags: c#, .net, archivo, pdf, async

```
    private void btnImprimir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        wc.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(DescargaDeDocumentoCompletada);
        Uri pdfurl = new Uri("https://filemanfe.000webhostapp.com/ManfeDatos.pdf");
        wc.DownloadFileAsync(pdfurl,"DatosManfe.pdf");

    }
    private void DescargaDeDocumentoCompletada(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Descarga Finalizada");

    }
```

Este es el codigo con el que realizo la descarga pero se descarga en el proyecto y no en descargas

Comment: si no le agregas una ruta al archivo, entonces se guarda en la carpeta donde estas ejecutando...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes agregarle la ruta de la siguiente forma:

```
private void btnImprimir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Obtenemos el nombre del usuario actual
    string userFolder = Environment.UserName;
    // Almacenamos la ruta de la carpeta de descargas en una string
    string pathToSaveFile = "C:\\Users\\" + userFolder + "\\Downloads\\";

    wc.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(DescargaDeDocumentoCompletada);
    Uri pdfurl = new Uri("https://filemanfe.000webhostapp.com/ManfeDatos.pdf");
    // Agregamos la ruta mas el nombre del archivo para guardarlo
    wc.DownloadFileAsync(pdfurl, pathToSaveFile + "DatosManfe.pdf");

}
private void DescargaDeDocumentoCompletada(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    string userFolder = Environment.UserName;
    string pathToSaveFile = "C:\\Users\\" + userFolder + "\\Downloads\\";
    MessageBox.Show("Descarga Finalizada, Ruta del archivo: " + pathToSaveFile);
}
```

Espero te sirva, Saludos!

Comment: Muchas gracias, si me sirvio